# Preg_replace цены

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Пытаюсь отфильтровать строчку с ценой, чтобы привести ее в считабельный формат. В исходном виде может выглядеть так (без кавычек): "2 200,00" 
Помогите составить регулярку, чтобы получалось "2200".
Пробовал так:

```
$result = preg_replace("/([^0-9,]\s)/iu","", $result);
```

Не получается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если требуется получить float, то можно сделать так:

```
$result = (float)strtr($result, array(',' => '.', ' ' => ''));
```

Если же достаточно целого:

```
$result = (int)preg_replace('/[^\d,]/', '', result);
```

Comment: Опередили).

Answer (score 0):

Решил следующим способом:

```
$result = preg_replace("/[,\s+]/iu","", $result);
```

Вроде работает.

Comment: И получите 220000, вместо 2200